# How to set progress dialog to max value in between

Tags: android, android-layout, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I have a progress dialog that takes 3 minutes to fill the progress.

If i get response from server earlier I want to fill progress to `100%`, and then disables it.

This is my code, but it does not fill the progress bar to 100%.

```
  progressBar.setProgress(100);
  progressBar.cancel();
  progressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

I have a separate layout for `progress dialog`, that i disable when i set `progressBar to 100`. May be that's the reason it fails to render the progress dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fills it to 100% but immediately makes it disappear, hence you're not seeing it. Try adding the code about turning your bar invisible in a runnable that starts only after you get the confirmation from the server

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        }
    }
```

then create a handler for ypur runnable:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

When you get the response from the server tell the handler to wait for x seconds and run the runnable

```
handler.postDelayed(r, 2000); //here it waits for 2 seconds (2000 mills)
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be an issue here:

The progressBar has a `setMax` method. So if your max is set to 2 (for example) if you use `progressBar.setProgress(1);` it will advance to 50%.

If you want to always fill it completely, perhaps using something like:

```
progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getMax());
```

Possible issue:
Im not sure if you should change this in the UIThread, because you are touching the UI, I would recommend to check it.

Hope this helps.